# Create directory in SFTP using Java

Tags: java, directory, streaming, sftp

I need to create a directory structure with files and several folders within folders, zip them and send them via SFTP to another folder.

More details:

From a mainframe I am getting information which is being transformed to PDFs succesfully, now I am required to create the following structure:

'**mainFolder**' that contains:

'**folderNumber1**' -- empty

'**folderNumber2**' -- empty

'**folderNumber3**' -- folder containing Files

'**counterOfFilesExtracted**.txt' (yes a txt file with the amount of files extracted)

all that inside of another folder, and then that main folder needs to be zipped.

so -> 'mainFolder.zip' --> 'mainFolder' --> 3 folders and 1 txt file --> in one of those folders, put the PDFs

I CANNOT use physical locations or storage, can this be achieved in one single java class at the end of the process?

If you wanna put some code great, but Im mainly asking for directions or ideas, I guess the only way to do this is via streams.

I can connect to SFTP via Java, I can zip the files and folder and create the structure perfectly, LOCALLY though, which is useless since this has to be on cloud, would it be to nasty if I create several SFTP connections, and create the directory, so at the end I can just dump info into those created folders by me in the SFTP?

I am able to do this but using my PC as destination, so its easier since I am creating the structure with File.io class anywhere I want, but how can this be achieved without saving anything anywhere, except obviously at the end to the SFTP folder